# SQL Multi Subtract

Tags: sql, sql-update, set, where-clause

I try a multi subtract with many `WHERE`:

```
UPDATE  `product`
SET  `quantity` =  quantity-1
WHERE  `upc` =11000000803;
WHERE  `upc` =11000000802;
WHERE  `upc` =11000000804;
```

I know that I can't have more than one `WHERE`.

I want to subtract the same value in quantity on each upc

I'm looking how I can do that.

Thank you :)

Comment: I have try CASE but I don't think it's the good way to do

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try

```
UPDATE product set quantity=quantity-1
WHERE  upc in (11000000803, 11000000802, 11000000804);
```

or

```
UPDATE product set quantity=quantity-1
WHERE  upc in ('11000000803', '11000000802', '11000000804');
```

Comment: Thank you ! I wasn't know for the "in"